# Reference appears as excluded in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, class-library

I have created my own class library. I added the dll from that class library into my web application project. Everything works fine. I can call the classes from that lib etc... However when I open my bin folder from VS 2008, then I do not see my dll. I can see it only when I click "show all files" icon from the solution explorer.

Now when I take a look at my references tab from my project properties I can see the DLL and the path is still pointing to the bin folder of my 3rd class lib and the Copy Local is set to true. I already cleaned my wap project/recompiled it etc.. I am not sure why its doing that.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using project references?

Comment: The projects aren't in the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly did you add the dll into your project?  If all you did was add a reference to the file location, then it's perfectly normal you're not seeing the DLL in Solution Explorer.  Why do you need to see it if you can acess the classes fine?

To see it in Solution Explorer you need to add it explicitly...(Show All Files, right-click, Include in Project) If you've done that and you still can't see it... well THEN we have a mystery.  :)

Comment: I thought that by adding the dll using the "Add reference" would automatically add it to the project as well. So anytime I need to add a reference, I would need to use "include in project"? It doesnt make sense to me, because if I am using "add reference", then it should be obvious that I want to include it as well.

Comment: The file itself does not automatically get included in the project.  It's more akin to a data file your code is referencing.  If you load "data.xml" via code, you'd probably want to add that to your project for easy access to it, but it doesn't get included automatically.  In the project file it is a "Reference" node rather than a "Content" node... but you can add the latter.